# How to calculate the number of lines in source code

Tags: bash, terminal, lines-of-code

As the title says how i can calculate the total number of lines in a source code folder using bash commands

Comment: In what programming languge(s) is your sorce code written? Do you need to ignore compiled files?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [`sloccount`](https://dwheeler.com/sloccount/)

> "SLOCCount", a set of tools for counting physical Source Lines of Code (SLOC) in a large number of languages of a potentially large set of programs

Comment: @flyer I don't think it supports QML

Answer (score 12):

You can just use

```
find . -name '*.php' | xargs wc -l
```

Comment: You probably want to use `-type f` to get only files, and append a `tail -1` to only get the total.  Also, unfortunately, this doesn't work if you have any filenames with spaces in them; `find . -type f -exec wc -l {} + | tail -1` works as long as you don't have too many files.

Answer (score 11):

Use [cloc](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc). It supports about 80 languages.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like:

```
find . -name "*.java" -exec cat {} \; | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions would be

1. Use a `find` command as in Barti's answer to locate all the files
2. Use `sed` or something to [strip out all the comments](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/academic/sed-remove-c-cpp-comments/)
3. Don't do it at all

SLOC is a very, very misleading way to measure software.  Bill Gates said it was like estimating the quality of an aircraft by weight, and it may be the only helpful thing he ever said.

Comment: Your last paragraph is wrong, because it depends on what you're trying to measure about the software.  Consider, for instance, that the weight of a Boeing jetliner and its cost are roughly proportional -- which means that, given a regression line through the costs and weights of current 737, 747, 767, and 777 product lines, you can guess the cost of a 787 Dreamliner to within about 15% given its weight.  Development times and SLOC count have that sort of proportionality within similar classes of software and similar development teams.

Comment: I think that's an excellent analogy.  Very similar planes made by the same company, and there is a close correlation between weight and cost.  You compare two programs written by the same person, in the same language, yeah, you can probably correlate SLOC with time to write, number of bugs, and so on.  In *any other case* ...

Answer (score -1):

This will count empty lines as well, but it's easy. Go to the specific directory you wanna check and do

```
find . | wc
```

Answer (score -1):

Already been answered, just giving another way using `awk` which you'll definitely have.

`cat *.ext | awk 'BEGIN{i=0;} {i++;} END{print "Lines ", i}'`

I only also suggest this because it can be easily edited to add patterns (such as comments) for lines that you don't want to count.